# Case Statement VBA

Tags: vba

I have a value in cell in cell A1 (0.45) and in B1 I want the output of this function which should be 5.

```
Function createStakes(rng As Range) As Double

Dim kelly As Double
kelly = rng.Value

Dim stake As Double


kelly = Round(kelly, 3)
    
Select Case kelly
Case Is <= 0.1
stake = 1
Case Is <= 0.15
stake = 1.5
Case Is <= 0.2
stake = 2
Case Is <= 0.25
stake = 2.5
Case Is <= 0.3
stake = 3
Case Is <= 0.35
stake = 3.5
Case Is <= 0.4
stake = 4
Case Is < 0.45
stake = 4.5
Case Else
stake = 5
End Select


End Function
```

Nothing is returned. I've tried debugging and the function itself seems to work but the cell has a zero. I've also tried running another module and returning the output of the function as a variable but it always returns a zero?

I've tried other functions which do work so I am not sure what is going wrong?

Comment: `CreateStakes = stake`, right before `End Function`.

Comment: Note that `Round` uses bankers rounding. In most cases, `WorksheetFunction.Round` is preferable.

Comment: @BigBen thanks! I knew it would be something simple. I haven't done anything in VB for years now. Appreciate the help.